# How to count from a start to a maximum then begin again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count in Python from a startvalue to a maxvalue and when the maxvalue is reached begin again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

def nummern_hoch(b_nummer, letzte_nummer):    
    for i in range(letzte_nummer,999):        
        print(f"{b_nummer}{i}")

def main():
    nummern_hoch(44213, 47)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the first 5 numbers must always be the same, the next must count up to max 999 and then start again from the startvalue (here `letzte_nummer`).

Edit:
Thats for a  number addet after a fix number to be counted up to a maximum of digits. After the limit is reached it should start from 0 looks like 100047 100048, 100049,..., 1000999,10000,10001...

how could I get this?

Answer (score 4):

Well you can just add a `while True:` wrapping the `for` loop:

```py
def nummern_hoch(const, start):
    while True:    
        for i in range(start,999):        
            print(f"{const}{i}")
        start = 0
```

Or alternatievley you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) with the help of [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to *concatenate* two `range`s together. So we could do something like::

```py
from itertools import cycle, chain

def nummern_hoch(const, start):    
    for i in cycle(chain(range(start, 999), range(start))):
        print(f"{const}{i}")
```

**Ex:**

```py
for i in cycle(range(3)):
    print(i, end=' ')

# 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 ...

for i in cycle(chain(range(3, 6), range(3))):
    print(i, end=' ')

# 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 ...
```

Comment: Thanx, this works both.
but I found, that my problem brought another problem.
in the first time it should start with the startvalue and the next rounds, when the myvalue is reached, it should start with 0.
eg 47,48,49,50,0,1,2,3...

Comment: Not sure I understand @czil . Why do you start from `0` after `50`?

Comment: Thats a number addet after a fix number to be counted up to a maximum of digits. After the limit is reached it should start from 0 looks like 100047 100048, 100049,..., 1000999,10000,10001

Comment: @czil did that help you?